# Insert to specific sheet name based on referral name

Tags: php, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I created a writeTosheet() PHP function which writes the form data to the corresponding google sheet name. The function takes in the referral name as a parameter and writes the data to the sheet corresponding to the referral name.

```
// Write to conditional tabs based on referral names
if (isset($_SESSION['ref1_name']) && isset($_SESSION['quote_fullname']) && isset($_SESSION['quote_service'])) {
  writeToSheet($_SESSION['ref1_name']);
  $rlevel = "T1";
}

if (isset($_SESSION['ref2_name']) && isset($_SESSION['quote_fullname']) && isset($_SESSION['quote_service'])) {
  writeToSheet($_SESSION['ref2_name']);
  $rlevel = "T2";
}

if (isset($_SESSION['ref3_name']) && isset($_SESSION['quote_fullname']) && isset($_SESSION['quote_service'])) {
  writeToSheet($_SESSION['ref3_name']);
  $rlevel = "T3";
}
```

The code then calls the writeToSheet() function for each referral name that is set in the session variables and if the quote details are also set. It passes the corresponding referral name to the function which is also the name of the google sheet tab/name as it should match.

```
function writeToSheet($ref_name) {
  global $MasterUrl, $dt, $tm, $quote_branch, $quote_service, $quote_fullname, $quote_vmm, $rlevel;
  $scriptURL = $MasterUrl;
  $ref_name = ucfirst(strtolower($ref_name));
  $sheetName = $ref_name;
  $surl = $scriptURL . "?referralSheetName=" . urlencode($sheetName);

  $form_data = [
    'Date' => $dt,
    'Time' => $tm,
    'Branch' => $quote_branch,
    'Service' => $quote_service,
    'Full Name' => $quote_fullname,
    'Vehicle Make & Model' => $quote_vmm,
    'Referral Level' => $rlevel,
    'Status' => $ref_name
  ];

  $options = [
    'http' => [
        'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => http_build_query($form_data),
    ],
  ];

  $context  = stream_context_create($options);
  $result = file_get_contents($surl, false, $context);
  
  $_SESSION['result'] = $result;
  var_dump($result);
}
```

Here's the google app script:

```
function doPost (e) {
  var lock = LockService.getScriptLock();
  lock.tryLock(10000);

  try {
    var sheetName = e.parameter.referralSheetName || 'Master'; // use 'Master' as default sheet name
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(scriptProp.getProperty('key'));
    var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(sheetName);

    var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
    var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1;

    var newRow = headers.map(function(header) {
      return header === 'timestamp' ? new Date() : e.parameter[header];
    });

    sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, newRow.length).setValues([newRow]);

    return ContentService
      .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'success', 'row': nextRow }))
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  } catch (e) {
    return ContentService
      .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'error', 'error': e }))
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  } finally {
    lock.releaseLock();
  }
}
```

[Picture: Here's the Google Sheet Tabs/Name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcRFA.png)

Every time I test the code, it only writes to the default sheet name and not to the desired sheet name, which is defined in the referralSheetName parameter.

Comment: I think that in your script, from your provided image, for example, when `$ref_name` is `Ryan`, the values are put in the `Ryan` sheet. So, in your situation, when you redeployed your Web Apps for reflecting the latest script, what result will you obtain? When you deployed Web Apps as a new version, the endpoint is changed. Please be careful about this. If you want to use the same endpoint, you can see the detail of this report. [Ref](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)

Comment: Yes, thank you, im aware about the endpoint and new version, I copied the new deployment web app url. I added var_dump($result); and I get these errors: string(29) "{"result":"error","error":{}}" string(29) "{"result":"error","error":{}}" string(29) "{"result":"error","error":{}}". And in executions the status is completed, i dont see any failed attempt. Please see screenshot: [link](https://prnt.sc/i4WzdCtx2JjI)

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, your Web Apps has the latest script. Is my understanding correct? If my understanding is correct, when I tested the Web Apps using your Google Apps Script and your PHP script using the sample values, no error occurs. `{"result":"success","row":###}` is returned. So, I cannot replicate your situation. I apologize for this. But, I would like to support you. So, can you provide the detailed flow for correctly replicating your current issue? I would like to confirm it.

Comment: By the way, in your question, you say `Every time I test the code, it only writes to the default sheet name and not to the desired sheet name, which is defined in the referralSheetName parameter.`. In this case, doesn't no error occurs? I'm confused about your current situation. I apologize.